# Get all elements from parent table which match certain criteria in a child table (one-to many)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let's say I have two tables, for instance:

Table A:

- id number
- [any other fields]

Table B:

- id number (it's the same id from table A, so a foreign key)
- some_value varchar2

Table B can have many entries for one Table A entry.

With this setup, if I have some hibernate query for table A, I can see how many entries I have in Table B by adding this Criterion:

```
Restrictions.sizeGt("TableB", 0)
```

This will run a query like this one:

```
select id from table_a tba where 0 < (select count(*) from table_b where tba.id = id)
```

However, I need to be able to add a restriction that will compare all values from some list as part of this restriction, some sql code like:

```
select id from table_a tba where 0 < (select count(*) from table_b where tba.id = id and some_value in (...))
```

With the restriction, I can come to the count but without the list comparision I need. Any attempts to add criterions to the main query have gotten me to include the second table as a join, which I don't need...

Have to say that Table A and Table B are already persistent classes, Table B is defined as follows on Table A mapping:

```
    <map name="TableB" table="table_b" cascade="all, delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="id"/>
        <index column="some_value" type="string"/>
        <one-to-many class="myClassDef"/>
    </map>
```

So, the question is, how can I add the Criterion to the sizeGt restriction so that I can consider other fields apart from the primary key defined in the mappings?

Regards

Comment: Write a detached criteria for the subquery. Then use `Subqueries.lt(0, detachedCriteria)`. If you're stuck, show the code you've tried. Or use HQL.

Comment: @JBNizet, seems just like what I'm looking for. Since I'm working over a wrapped Hibernate API, I will first have to find out how to get the Hibernate Session so I can have direct access to the Criterias I need... Will post back if it does (or does not) work...

Comment: Well, at the end I had to implement a different solution as Table B has maybe hundred times the information of Table A, making the query I was looking for very inefficient. However, I'm sure the solution is just what I was asking for and it will work, so if you put it as a reply I will be happy to accept it as a solution...